# cleaner code for validation of string with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to do something like

```
if re_validate("/\d+/\d+", token):
    items.append( token)
```

instead of this stuff whose meaning is not apparent:

```
    maybe_item = re.findall("/\d+/\d+", token)
    if maybe_item and maybe_item[0] == token:
        items.append( token)
```

My code finds all strings that match the pattern, and sees if the only "match" is the same as the input itself. I am looking for a simpler way.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Is that way -->

Comment: @IanAuld - Did you just say "code review is this way" and then point at yourself? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` matches the start of the string, while `$` matches the end of the string. You need to use `^/\d+/\d+$`. That way, the only possible match is the whole string.